# Oracle / reciprocal path

Tags: oracle, path

I have a query that get the path between two points:

```
with nodes (node) as (
    select 'A' from dual union all
    select 'B' from dual union all
    select 'C' from dual union all
    select 'D' from dual
),
connected_nodes (node_1,node_2 ) as
(
    select 'A','B' from dual union all
    select 'B','C' from dual union all
    select 'B','D' from dual union all
    select 'A','C' from dual union all
    select 'A','D' from dual union all
    select 'D','C' from dual union all
    select 'C','D' from dual
)
select ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(node_1, '->'), '->') as path,
       level -1 as hops
from
    (
    select node as node_1, node_2
    from nodes
           left join connected_nodes
             on(node = node_1)
    )         
where node_1 = 'C'               
connect by nocycle prior node_2 = node_1
               and prior node_1 is not null
start with node_1 = 'A'
```

it works just fine so if I need to get the path from A to C, it gives :

```
PATH             HOPS
---------- ----------
A->B->C             2
A->B->D->C          3
A->C                1
A->D->C             2
```

what I need is that to have the path reciprocal , meaning getting from A to C is the same as getting from C to A , but it's not the case in the above query , as if I request the path from C to A it doesn't return data.

can you please help me adjust the query to fulfill my needs ?

Comment: Do you mean when you just swap to `where node_1 = 'A'` and `start with node_1 = 'C'`? Are you expecting exactly the same output, or the same paths but in reverse (`C->D->A`)?

Comment: yes I need the same paths but in reverse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a bi-directional graph then use `UNION ALL` to include both `node_1, node_2` and the reverse `node_2, node_1` in the query:

```
with connected_nodes (node_1,node_2 ) as
(
    select 'A','B' from dual union all
    select 'B','C' from dual union all
    select 'B','D' from dual union all
    select 'A','C' from dual union all
    select 'A','D' from dual union all
    select 'D','C' from dual union all
    select 'C','D' from dual
)
select SUBSTR(sys_connect_by_path(node_2, '->'), 3) as path,
       level -1 as hops
from   ( SELECT node_1, node_2 FROM connected_nodes
         UNION ALL
         SELECT node_2, node_1 FROM connected_nodes
         UNION ALL
         SELECT null, 'C' FROM DUAL -- Fake connection to start vertex which
                                    -- prevents C being revisited with the
                                    -- NOCYCLE keyword.
       )
where node_2 = 'A'
start with node_1 IS null
connect by nocycle prior node_2 = node_1;
```

**Output**:

```
PATH        HOPS
----------- ----
C->A        1
C->B->A     2
C->B->D->A  3
C->D->A     2
C->D->B->A  3
C->D->A     2
C->D->B->A  3
```

Comment: Aside from the duplicates, why is `C->B->D->A` a valid path?

Comment: @AlexPoole I prefixed the answer with "If you have a bi-directional graph". If so, then there is an edge `B->C` and an edge `B->D` and you can traverse them in both directions.

Comment: That seems like a big 'if' from the sample data (it wouldn't have both D,C and C,D maybe?) but OK, I missed the significance of that. To avoid the duplicate then, if it does have some/all edges both ways, should your `union all`s just be `union`s?

Comment: @AlexPoole That depends on the semantic meaning of traversing an edge - if there is no difference traversing the edge `C->D` or traversing the edge `D->C` in the reverse direction then, yes, `UNION ALL` could be `UNION`. However, if there is additional meaning to the edge followed then they are different paths and `UNION ALL` is appropriate and there are two distinct `C->D->A` paths.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm not up on graph theory (clearly!). Good thing I'm here to learn *8-)

Answer (score 1):

To get the reciprocal path you need to walk the tree the other way; I don't think you can do that in one hierarchical query without introducing some weird diversions.

You could union together both search directions:

```
with connected_nodes (node_1,node_2 ) as
(
    select 'A','B' from dual union all
    select 'B','C' from dual union all
    select 'B','D' from dual union all
    select 'A','C' from dual union all
    select 'A','D' from dual union all
    select 'D','C' from dual union all
    select 'C','D' from dual
)
select ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(node_1, '->'), '->') as path,
       level -1 as hops
from connected_nodes
where node_1 = 'C'               
connect by nocycle prior node_2 = node_1
               and prior node_1 is not null
start with node_1 = 'A'
union all
select ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(node_1, '->'), '->') as path,
       level -1 as hops
from connected_nodes
where node_1 = 'C'
connect by nocycle prior node_1 = node_2
               and prior node_2 is not null
start with node_1 = 'A'
/
```

which still gets the same result for your initial conditions:

```
PATH                                                     HOPS
-------------------------------------------------- ----------
A->B->C                                                     2
A->B->D->C                                                  3
A->C                                                        1
A->D->C                                                     2
```

but with all referenced to `A` and `C` reversed gets the reverse path:

```
with connected_nodes (node_1,node_2 ) as
(
    select 'A','B' from dual union all
    select 'B','C' from dual union all
    select 'B','D' from dual union all
    select 'A','C' from dual union all
    select 'A','D' from dual union all
    select 'D','C' from dual union all
    select 'C','D' from dual
)
select ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(node_1, '->'), '->') as path,
       level -1 as hops
from connected_nodes
where node_1 = 'A'               
connect by nocycle prior node_2 = node_1
               and prior node_1 is not null
start with node_1 = 'C'
union all
select ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(node_1, '->'), '->') as path,
       level -1 as hops
from connected_nodes
where node_1 = 'A'
connect by nocycle prior node_1 = node_2
               and prior node_2 is not null
start with node_1 = 'C'
/

PATH                                                     HOPS
-------------------------------------------------- ----------
C->A                                                        1
C->B->A                                                     2
C->D->A                                                     2
C->D->B->A                                                  3
```

You don't need the inline view, or to refer to the `node` table directly, at least with your sample data. The first branch of the union does a hierarchical query in one direction; the second branch goes in the other direction, swapping the references in the `prior` and `not null` checks. One branch will always get no rows, and the other branch gets the paths you want; the start/end conditions determine which branch gets which.